# How to make a post request in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, curl

Here's the cURL request which it works:

```
curl -H 
'X-New-ID: weR1RRzRw3R3R3Rz1' 
-H 'Brand: 1' 
-H 'X-Device-Version: 4.02' 
-H 'X-Device-Source: 6' 
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
-H 'User-Agent: Dalv1k/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Andr0id 5.1; Go0gle Nexus 10 - 5.1.0 - API 22 - 2560x1600_1 Build/LM227D)' 
-H 'Host: api.autoigs.com' 
--data-binary '{"areaId":10,"cityId":1,"countryId":1,"kickId":0}' --compressed 'https://api.autoigs.com/apiAndroid/v1/kicks'
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to figure that out as well (like curl from cli) Though I would like to use nodejs to send this request. How do i do this?

Comment: [`request`](https://github.com/request/request)

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) package, you can do it like this:

```js
const request = require('request');

request.post({
  url: 'https://api.autoigs.com/apiAndroid/v1/kicks', 
  form: {"areaId":10,"cityId":1,"countryId":1,"kickId":0},
  json: true,
  headers: {
    'X-New-ID': 'weR1RRzRw3R3R3Rz1',
    'Brand': '1',
    'X-Device-Version': '4.02',
    'X-Device-Source': '6',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US',
    'User-Agent': 'Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1; Google Nexus 10 - 5.1.0 - API 22 - 2560x1600_1 Build/LMY47D)',
  },
}, function(err, response, body) {
  if(err) {
    console.error('error', err);
    // handle error!
    return;
  }

  // body contains response body
  console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, I've tried that I doesn't give any response. but when i Try to cURL command it. I get response, which that's weird.

Comment: @mzaboss Did you get any errors then? That node.js code should be equivalent to your cURL command...

Comment: But for some reason its not getting me the same responses.

Comment: Is this URL is correct? since I am not getting any response

Comment: abdulbarik: URL is different, above is just an example. Got skype?